# Should I use a class or data structure to store this data

Tags: java

I've got a small list of data that looks something like the following:

```
ProductName ----  Price   ---- Path  
Part1  ---------  5.99  ------  /myDirectory/Part1.png  
Part2  ---------  15.99 -----   /myDirectory/Part2.png  
Part3  ---------  5.00 ------   /myDirectory/Part3.png
```

This is a static list that's never going to change.

What I want to be able to do is pick a product from this list at random, then return the name, price and path for that item.

Should I use a class for this, or a data structure?  I started defining a multi-dimensional array, but this didn't feel right. It feels like I should be using a class here, but I'm not sure how I'd initialise the data, or pick a random product.

Comment: A class is definitely more readable.. `product.name` is much better than `product[0]`

Comment: Reads like __Design choice / question__, that should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com. Always add your [example] code (e.g. your _multi-dimensional array_, or _class with attempts to initialize data_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a class for this, like

```
public class Product{
    String productName;
    double price; // I like BigDecimal in this case, as it is more precise
    String path;
}
```

And then you need to have a `List<Product>` somewhere you need, like:

```
public List<Product> fillList(){
    List<Product> productList = new Arraylist<>();
    productList.add(new Product("name1", 4.99, "path/To/File.jpg"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Totally agree, especially the `BigDecimal` price. The OP also asked how to initialize data and how to select randomly. Add this to your answer to complete.

Comment: Post now contains a short overview on how to initialize data

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a class and then put the details into a HashMap.

E.G. Create a class called ProductDetails, which would have all the fields that you would require.

Then place the objects into a hashmap; assuming the ProductNames are unique. So you will have something like `Map<String, ProductDetails> productDetails = new HashMap<>();` where the String can be the name of the product and the Product details will be the object.

PS: When creating the ProductDetails object do not forget to override the equals and hashcode - the reason

> You must override hashCode() in every class that overrides equals().
>   Failure to do so will result in a violation of the general contract
>   for Object.hashCode(), which will prevent your class from functioning
>   properly in conjunction with all hash-based collections, including
>   HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable.

*Joshua Bloch - Effective Java*